# C++ API: how to subscribe to a change in a particular variable on a KDB/Q server?

Tags: c++, api, push-notification, kdb

Could you please help me to understand how to subscribe for notification to changes in a particular (global) variable on a Q server from a C++ API?

Example: on a Q server I have a variable var:0. I want the server to notify interested (i.e. those, which subscribed to it) C++ clients whenever value of var changes. Is it possible? If it is, could you please provide a simple example of how to set it up?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If var is a global, you could use .z.vs (value set) - cleaner than constantly checking the value of a var with a timer...

When the global is changed - this handler would be triggered and you could implement logic within in it to send a message to your C applications.

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zvs-value-set

Comment: @ Chromozorz, thank you for your reply! My understanding is that .z.vs would send notifications to **all** processes when **any** global variable has changed. I wanted to know if it is possible for a **particular** process to subscribe by to a change in a **particular** variable. Or I have to write the needed custom code myself?

Comment: I guess you could add the logic in .z.vs. Have a dictionary mapping your processes to the variables they are subscribed to. Then inside .z.vs do a lookup using the variable which will return the handle of the particular process subscribed to that and send them a message.

`varmap:`var1`var2`var3!5 6 7i`
`.z.vs:{varmap[x[0]]("Your particular variable has changed")}`

Comment: @ Chromozorz Thank you! That is what I was thinking about doing, but wanted to check if the wheel has already been invented ;) I guess not...